# Virtual environment not activating in visual studio code windows 11

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

**While enabling virtual environment in vscode i am getting this error
it i also get same error without using python environment manager extension**

& : File C:\Users\mudit\vscode\python django projects\dev\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\mudit\vscode\python django  projects\dev\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting  execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:3

- & "c:/Users/mudit/vscode/python django projects/dev/venv/Scripts/Acti ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

**[check out this screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8FDJ.png)**

Comment: I think your screenshot did not get attached properly.

Comment: check out now bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your powershell execution policy has to be updated.

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in powershell should fix it

Make sure you run this command in a Powershell console which you have opened with option (right click) "Run as Administrator"

Once done, you can verify if it was set properly using command `Get-ExecutionPolicy`